# How to convert an existing ASP.NET Web API to Azure Mobile Service?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-mobile-services

Recently announced at Microsoft Build is the ability to convert an existing ASP.NET Web API to an Azure Mobile Service. I was curious as to if anyone has successfully done this yet, and the steps needed to do so.

Things I've tried thus far:

1. Added the Azure Mobile Service .NET Backend & Azure Mobile Service -
   Entity Framework Nuget Packages to my existing ASP.NET Web API
   project.
2. Resolved an issue with OWIN and AMS(ZUMO) conflicting Startup.cs assemblies.
3. Ensured the ASP.NET Web API compiles locally, and published as an Azure Mobile Service.

However whenever publishing, it seems I only get a runtime error on the server.

Here was the best example of potentially doing this: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/3-623

Secondly I've looked a bit into just running the OWIN pipeline via: http://www.strathweb.com/2014/02/running-owin-pipeline-new-net-azure-mobile-services/

I know that this is in a preview mode, but figured some document trail would help!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding your existing WebAPI assets to Mobile Services project you create from VS? This will make sure all the right things are wired up. Also, check the Logs tab in the portal for any clues.

Answer (score 0):

This should help..

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azuremobile/archive/2014/04/10/creating-an-azure-mobile-services-net-backend-from-scratch.aspx

Thanks 
Supreet